# Suppress "The method does not override the inherited method since it is private to a different package."

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

How can I suppress the following error with the `@SuppressWarning` annotation?

> The method `Foo.trololo()` does not override the inherited method from `Bar` since it is private to a different package

So far as I can tell the only way is to blanket the entire method with `@SuppressWarning("all")` which I would prefer not to do.

---

*For clarification: The naming and scope of both methods is a deliberate choice and the two classes were deliberately put into different packages knowing the methods would not be visible  to each other. I am merely looking to declare that I acknowledge what I am doing and would not like to be warned of it.*

Comment: That seems like an error that you shouldn't suppress...

Comment: The warning is a result of coincidentally named, package-scoped methods in both the base class (out of my control) and my own class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What it means (you probably know this already)

It means that, even though your method has the same name as a (non-private) method in the super class, it doesn't override that method.

#### Regarding the warning message

This is an Eclipse-specific warning. Nothing in the language spec says that it *should* produce this warning. It's an "IDE-specific feature" if you so like. Therefore there is no "generic" way of suppressing the message.

(Note for instance that `javac` does not produce this warning.)

#### How to disable this warning (in Eclipse)

(I know *you* are not looking for this, but some other visitor of this page may!)

To disable this warning, you go to

*Window* -> *Preferences* -> *Java* -> *Compiler* -> *Errors / Warnings*

and set "*Method does not override package visible method*" to "*Ignore*".

Comment: As this is a library project I was hoping to avoid polluting the referencing projects with warnings as well. Since this is likely an extremely rare situation in the first place (the first that I have ever seen it) I will have to settle with disabling the warning. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I can see how this is an annoying situation. You're welcome :-)

Comment: You can also do this per-project rather than for the entire workspace. In the Eclipse _Package Explorer_, right click the project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings

Answer (score 2):

This warning means that you have a package-private method `trololo` in `Bar`, and a `trololo` method in `Foo`, which extends `Bar`, but is not in the same package.

If your goal is to override the `Bar.trololo` method with `Foo.trololo`, then the Bar.trololo method must be made protected. If your goal is to have two different methods, it would be better to name the second one `tralala` to make it much clearer and avoid confusion.

Comment: Both the name and scope of my method was deliberate and the "collision" with the base class is just an unfortunate coincidence. I was not looking to override the base functionality nor interact with it directly in any way.

Comment: Then I would rename your method to avoid confusion. It's package-scoped, so it shouldn't have a big impact.

Comment: That will probably be the final solution which I will work towards. The project in which this occurs is also a library so it is not as quick as a simple method refactor but being package scoped the API is only used internally so the number of consumers is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Suppress Warning a specific project, in the Eclipse Package Explorer, right click the project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings then Check "Enable project specific settings" -> Name shadowing and conflicts then set "Method does not override package visible method" to "Ignore". Rebuild the project and warning will go away. Done!!